# Reload nginx RTMP config file without restarting nginx

Tags: linux, webserver, nginx, video-streaming, rtmp

My scenario is: I have an nginx server that is used to forward RTMP live stream to YouTube. I would like to add some additional destinations in the config file (nginx.conf), while the livestream is running.

After I change the config file, I use the nginx reload command:

```
nginx -s reload
```

Unfortunately, the changes in the config file (i.e the extra destinations), doesn't take effect until the nginx server is restarted using:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

With restarting nginx server, there are seconds of downtime happen in the stream.

**Is there a way to change the nginx-rtmp config without having to restart the nginx server?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the short answer is, you can't. The reason is that nginx will gracefully handle any pending requests, before the nginx process handling those requests dies. As rtmp-streams are longlasting connections, this does not happen, and the old config stays in place as long as your videostream is up. You could use a workaround using ffmpeg though, to fetch the stream from your server and copy it to your preferred destination.

```
ffmpeg -y -analyzeduration 0 -rtmp_live live -i "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/my-live-stream" -c:v copy -c:a copy -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<your-youtube-key-here>"
```